# Installing Dave Carolls Sublime Lightning - windows

Tags: lightning-aura-components, force.com, lightning-connect, force-cli

I'm trying to install a plugin for salesforce Lightning by Dave Carroll, unfortunately, run into some issues. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or something else is wrong. I followed his tutorial [how to install the plug-in](https://github.com/dcarroll/sublime-lightning)
, but every time i open the sublime T 3 i get this error.[image]

I really appreciate your help and for taking time for replying.

Naruto.

Comment: It requires force-cli which leads me to believe you have to have the force-cli be executable in your environment's path variable.  If you open a command window does this command return anything?
force whoami

Comment: The bottom line of the dialog also hints at this.  They seem to suggest moving the force cli app directly into sublime's default path.  I believe sublime reads the system path, so changing the Windows path to include the force-cli location should work for you.

Comment: @drakored thank you for taking time to reply to this question. That did the trick. I added the to the path but i missed a forward slash. thanks once again.

Comment: No problem, added an answer so it can be closed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line of the dialog also hints at this. They seem to suggest moving the force cli app directly into sublime's default path. I believe sublime reads the system path, so changing the Windows path to include the force-cli location should work for you. by @drakored

Answer (score 2):

It requires force-cli which leads me to believe you have to have the force-cli be executable in your environment's path variable.  You can test if Sublime is able to reach the force-cli by opening a command window and testing the following command.

```
force whoami
```

If not, find the location of the installed force binary and add it to your Windows path.  There are various ways to do that per version (Windows or *nix,OSX as well).  Here is a good resource for how to do that.  I won't directly post the info here since it goes a bit outside of the scope of this exchange site:

https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: Thank you, I tried to do that but I guess that's not the right way.

Comment: No problem.  If the solution was what you needed there is a button on the post to accept an answer as the solution.  For issues like this I usually add any testing/problem solving questions to comments first on the question then add an answer later if it was the right path (the answer is generally for users later on who find the question and have similar issues).